# How to read data from random URL's using Python and MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

Currently I am working on a POC using Python 3.4.3 and MongoDB as technologies.

I need to search for any string like **"Financial" or "Apple quarterly result"**, etc. in **www.socialmention.com** website. The result will be multiple URL and it will be random. Now I need to parse each of these links and read the article, comments, likes, user details, etc.

Till now I succeeded to capture the random links URL's from socialmention and then my idea is to create a blogs dictionary in mongodb and maintain the information like below:

```
> db.blogs_dictionary.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55401455a1ce265d58f21049"),
    "blog_name" : "www.networkcomputing.com",
    "article" : "yes",
    "article_tag" : "div",
    "article_tag_type" : "id",
    "article_string" : "article-main",
    "article_multipage" : "yes",
    "article_multipage_tag" : "span",
    "article_multipage_tag_type" : "class",
    "article_multipage_tag_string" : "blue strong allcaps",
    "article_multipage_query_variable" : "page_number",
    "comments" : "yes",
    "comments_multipage" : "no",
    "comments_multipage_tag" : "",
    "comments_multipage_tag_type" : "",
    "comments_multipage_tag_string" : "",
    "comments_threaded" : "yes",
    "comments_threaded_query_variable" : "piddl_msgorder",
    "comments_threaded_query_value" : "thrd#msgs",
    "comments_main" : "yes",
    "comments_main_tag" : "div",
    "comments_main_tag_type" : "class",
    "comments_main_tag_string" : "comments-main",
    "user_name" : "yes",
    "user_name_tag" : "span",
    "user_name_tag_type" : "class",
    "user_name_tag_string" : "smaller strong black",
    "user_rank" : "yes",
    "user_rank_tag" : "span",
    "user_rank_tag_type" : "class",
    "user_rank_tag_string" : "smaller black",
    "comments_body" : "yes",
    "comments_body_tag" : "div",
    "comments_body_tag_type" : "class",
    "comments_body_tag_string" : "comment-body"
}
```

And then in the python code use some thing like ... if the link from socialmention website is there in my blog dictonary ... then check the article and comments are present or not .. if present then open URL by URL and read the required contents .... but for all this to happen I need to pass the tags and search strings dynamically

```
for i in db.social_mention.find({},{"blog_name":1,"_id":0}):
   for j in db.blogs_dictionary.find({},{"blog_name":1,"_id":0}):
      if i['blog_name']==j['blog_name']:
         link=db.social_mention.find_one({"blog_name":i['blog_name']},{"link":1,"_id":0})
         url=link['link']
         print (url)
         if (db.blogs_dictionary.find({"blog_name":j['blog_name']},{"article":1,"_id":0})) == "yes":
            article_variables=db.blogs_dictionary.find({"blog_name":j['blog_name']},{"article":1,"article_tag":1,"article_tag_type":1,"article_string":1,"article_multi":1,"article_multipage_tag":1,"article_multipage_tag_type":1,"article_multipage_tag_string":1,"article_multipage_query_variable":1,"_id":0}).pretty()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
            data=soup.find(article_variables['article_tag'],article_variables['article_tag_type']=article_variables['article_string'])
            print (data.text)
```

But I get the error like keywords can't be expressions. Is there any other way to do this, or should I change my design?

Comment: What's exactly the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want to call [`find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) with an attributes dictionary, `attrs`:

```
data = soup.find(article_variables['article_tag'],
                 attrs={article_variables['article_tag_type']: article_variables['article_string']})
```

The reason: you can not pass a keyword argument using a string for the identifier, i.e. in

```
article_variables['article_tag_type']=article_variables['article_string']
```

`article_variables['article_tag_type']` is not a valid identifier for a keyword argument. A general workaround is to use a dictionary and unpack it like this:

```
kwargs = {article_variables['article_tag_type']: article_variables['article_string']}
data=soup.find(article_variables['article_tag'], **kwargs)
```

But, since `find()` accepts the `attrs` dictionary, you can just pass it directly.